# Deactivating plone.app.toolbar and plone.app.widgets

Tags: plone

We were testing out the new plone.app.toolbar after [Kim's fancy PloneEDU demo last week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOVJ52efbgE), and unfortunately hit some snags upon deactivating it and it's dependent product, plone.app.widgets. Here's what we've got installed on this server:

- Plone 4.3
- Zope 2.13.19
- Python 2.7.3
- Plone Toolbar 1.3.0
- Plone Widgets 1.3.3

Our symptoms, after uninstalling the two products, are primarily that the green "edit bar" from normal Plone doesn't work, or is quirky.

If we leave plone.app.widgets installed, the green bar works mostly fine, except the "Add new" dropdown doesn't show up, it just kicks you to folder_factories on clicking "Add new". There are a few other weird things, but nothing drastic.

However! With both uninstalled: hitting the "edit" button on the green bar throws the following traceback error (in Firefox and Safari) —

Just wondering if these symptoms sound familiar or if they're easy to fix? If not we can probably live with the "Add new" not working, or else find a way to move everything to a new site on the server (it's a relatively small website still in development, so not urgent).

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 31, in _call
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 237, in _exec
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 177, in pt_render
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
   - Warning: Macro expansion failed
   - Warning: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 'macro'
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 522, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 867, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: file:/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/skins/archetypes/edit_macros.pt
   - Line 105, Column 20
   - Expression: <PythonExpr context.widget(field.getName(), mode='edit')>
   - Names:
      {'container': <PloneSite at /Honey>,
       'context': <Collection at /Honey/events/aggregator>,
       'default': <object object at 0x14e84e0>,
       'here': <Collection at /Honey/events/aggregator>,
       'loop': {u'field': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x7f51812a83d0>,
                u'fieldset': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x7f51810cc5d0>},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': (),
                   'state': <Products.CMFFormController.ControllerState.ControllerState object at 0x7f517c88a8d0>},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7f51812beba8>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://169.237.124.22:8080/Honey/events/aggregator/atct_edit>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <FSControllerPageTemplate at /Honey/atct_edit used for /Honey/events/aggregator>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PloneUser 'cydoval'>}
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in __call__
   - __traceback_info__: context.widget(field.getName(), mode='edit')
  Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 287, in widget
  Module Products.Archetypes.Renderer, line 26, in render
  Module Products.Archetypes.generator.widget, line 147, in __call__
AttributeError: Macro patterns_widget does not exist for <Collection at aggregator>
```

**Bonus!** Just tried adding a brand new Plone site on the same server — the drop-downs for both the green "add new" menu and the user preferences don't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the product from your buildout--remove from buildout, re-run buildout, restart clients. It seems that some of the plone.app.widgets overrides affect plone sites even when they're not activated.

plone.app.widgets is still in development and the version you're on probably isn't very safe to install on a production site.

Look for a new release soon--there was just a sprint that fixed a lot of bugs.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! So, taking it out of buildout and rerunning worked for fixing new Plone sites on this instance (they don't have the error), but the existing site that had had it installed didn't repair. The dropdowns still don't work on that site, and also hitting "Edit" doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't load TinyMCE. This works well enough for now though. Appreciate it, and can't wait to see your new release! :)

Comment: did you run the uninstall portal_setup step? That's reactivate js and css files that were deactivated for plone.app.widgets to work. Otherwise, you can manually change the bundle of all js and css that is marked "deprecated" to "default"